# When was the third-umpire review system entered in cricket?

Tags: cricket, officiating, history, trivia

When was the **third umpire review system(not DRS)** entered in cricket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third umpire review system debuted in Test cricket in November 1992 at Kingsmead, Durban for the South Africa vs. India series.

**Additional trivia**: Sachin Tendulkar became the first batsman to be dismissed (run out) by using television replays.

Source: [ESPNCricinfo](http://www.espncricinfo.com/wisdenalmanack/content/story/153619.html), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_umpire#History)